# MFC open type font features in programming

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

The code below is part my function which prints out telephone number. The function works correctly with the selected font and size except for one small problem in the output.

```
cDrucker* drucker;
CFont fontText;
LOGFONT logFont;
Int links = 125;

::ZeroMemory(&logFont, sizeof(LOGFONT));
logFont.lfHeight = -MulDiv(9.5, drucker->printerDC.GetDeviceCaps(LOGPIXELSY), 72);
logFont.lfWidth = 0;
logFont.lfEscapement = 0;
logFont.lfOrientation = 0;
logFont.lfWeight = FW_NORMAL;
logFont.lfItalic = FALSE;
logFont.lfUnderline = FALSE;
logFont.lfStrikeOut = FALSE;
logFont.lfCharSet = ANSI_CHARSET;
logFont.lfOutPrecision = OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS;
logFont.lfClipPrecision = CLIP_DFA_DISABLE;
logFont.lfQuality = CLEARTYPE_QUALITY;
logFont.lfPitchAndFamily = DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_SWISS;
strcpy_s(logFont.lfFaceName, "MetaOT-Book");
fontText.CreateFontIndirect(&logFont);

int y = 49 - 6 - 5;
drucker->printerDC.SelectObject(&fontText);
drucker->textOut("Telefon: (0123)456789", links, &y, false);
```

Output 1: The actual output that is printed by the function

output 2: The output I want.

[image: outputs]

The question is how i can avoid the alternative up and down pattern in output 1 and make it look like output 2 ?

I know this is how the font is suppose to print the number. it is by design in that way but in MS word using font options I can change it to my desired output. 
as shown in the below picture.

[image: font]

I dont want to use another font So I was wondering if I could achieve the same using my program.

Font and Size:

[image: f&s]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @ScY The question is how i can avoid the alternative up and down pattern in output 1 and make it look like output 2 ?

Comment: But in your code you are specifying a font size of 9.5pt. The output you want is way larger. Check in Microsoft Word. Confused ...

Comment: So the question isn't about the size, but about that the numbers aren't rendered on the same baseline?

Comment: OK. But, isn't that down to the design of the font itself?

Comment: Judging by [this image](https://www.whatfontis.com/img/F/F/FF-Meta-OT-Medium0.png) (from [this page](https://www.whatfontis.com/FF-Meta-OT-Medium.font)) it seems the "up and down" is part of the font itself, and nothing you can do about it. You might want to use another font maybe?

Comment: Also, you know you can view the font on your system with the Font manager in the control panel?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Sorry for the difference in the image size. Actually there is no problem with output size. The problem is that the numbers are not printed in straight line.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Yes your right the design of the font itself like that but i want to change it that why i am asking

Comment: @sanjayanravi You shouldn't be even attempting to change an actual font design. It is usually copyrighted. Just select a different font that is more to your liking. I expect you to be breaching copyright if you tried editing the design of an existing font - not to even mention the work involved. Just use another font. :)

Comment: @AndrewTruckle  I know that i can change the font and view fonts. but for business purpose I need to use this font and make the number print in a straight line. This feature is actually possible using MS WORD font dialog -> advanced menu -> number forms option. I would like to achieve the same using programming and I was wondering if any one could help me with the same.

Comment: But look at your images again. The font is not the same.Look at number 1 for example.  It is not that I don't trust you. This is interesting. But can you show us a screen grab of your font in Word with the numbers?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle  as you requested. the screen grab

Comment: Yes. Look at the digits. They are different fonts. It is substituting the numbers for a different font.

Comment: This is the OpenType `onum` feature, you want `lnum`.   Programmatically controlled by passing DWRITE_FONT_FEATURE_TAG_LINING_FIGURES to IDWriteTypography::AddFontFeature().  You'll have to no doubt change a lot of code to get there, start with [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729481(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @AndrewTruckle No it doesn't i tested in ms word it doesn't change the font.

Comment: @HansPassant : thank you I have a look at it

Comment: Hi. But look at the digits. Look at number 1. It is actually rendered differently. But I see you have an answer now.